# Reading multiple dictionary from a text file and then sorting it

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm getting the below output in a text file. I want to read this data as a dictionary and later sort it in order of 'chunk0','chunk1', and 'chunk2'.
I'm new to python and tried with json.dumps but not able to get the desired result. I've gone through all questions relating to this but not able to get any solution. Any help will be appreciated.

**{'chunk0': 'experience proof less'},{'chunk2': 'your power is sufficient i said'},{'chunk1': 'why should one halt on the way'},**

```
Below is my code, the output is a tuple. I'm not able to sort the data.
    import ast
    with open(os.path.join(path,'output.txt'), 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    your_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(s)

The result: 
({'chunk0': 'experience proof less'},
 {'chunk2': 'your power is sufficient I said'},
 {'chunk1': 'why should one halt on the way'}).
```

Secondly, I tried to save data using json.dumps and later read using json.loads. But seems that json cannot handle multiple dictionaries.

```
    output = {audio_name: ds.stt(audio)}
    f.write(json.dumps(output))
    with open(os.path.join(path,'output1.txt'), 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    your_dictionary = json.loads(f.read())

Getting this error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 36 (char 35)
```

Comment: "I'm new to python and tried with json.dumps but not able to get the desired result." Please show us what you tried and what the results were. Then explain what you want the results to be instead. We will be glad to help you from there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We do not write code for eachother, instead we help by modifying and solving eachothers problems with their own code.  Please submit code that you have already tried to make this a valid question.

Comment: The data you have posted is not valid JSON or a valid Python dictionary

Comment: Can you post the data of output1.txt

Comment: Hello Annop, below is the data of output1.txt: {"chunk0": "experience proof less"}{"chunk2": "your power is sufficient i said"}{"chunk1": "why should one halt on the way"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to store data from a dictionary and then sort the list.

```
st = '{"chunk0" : "experience proof less"},{"chunk2" : "your power is sufficient i said"},{"chunk1" : "why should one halt on the way"}'

import json

js = json.loads("["+st+"]")
print(js)

lst = []
for x in js:
    for j in x:
        lst.append([j, x[j]])
        
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'chunk0': 'experience proof less'}, {'chunk2': 'your power is sufficient i said'}, {'chunk1': 'why should one halt on the way'}]
[['chunk0', 'experience proof less'], ['chunk1', 'why should one halt on the way'], ['chunk2', 'your power is sufficient i said']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Anoop for help. I was struggling to implement the same from the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

```
  The output6.txt: {"chunk0": "experience proof less"},{"chunk2": "your power is sufficient i said"},{"chunk1": "why should one halt on the way"},  

    import json
    import os
    path = r'C:\Users\rakes\Desktop\deepspeech-0.6.1-models\audio'
    with open(os.path.join(path,'output6.txt'), 'r') as f:
         b = f.read()
         f.close()
    
    b_list = b.split(',')
    b_chunks = []
    for i in b_list[:-1]:
        chunk = json.loads(i)
        b_chunks.append(chunk)
    lst = []
    for x in b_chunks:
        print(x)
        for j in x:
            print(j)
            lst.append([j, x[j]])
    
    lst.sort()
  
    for item in lst:
        print(item[1])

>>> experience proof less
>>> why should one halt on the way
>>> your power is sufficient i said
```

The above code helps me to access the multiple strings from the text file and sort it. Thanks, Anoop for the guidance.

As I'm using for loops quite often. Any suggestion to implement the same which results in improving the code structure.